# cast go array with type alias

Tags: arrays, go

Say I have a defined type `Bytes` that is a bytes array as in below.  Is there a simple way to convert an array of arrays of byte to an array of Bytes and vice versa?

```
package main

type Bytes []byte

func main() {
    x := make([][]byte, 3)
    y := ([]Bytes)(x)
}
```

Comment: As it always helps using the right terminology (e.g. when doing online research): (1) `type Bytes []byte` is **not** an "alias". It's a defined (named) type, an alias is the thing with a `=` sign like `type Foo = Bar`. (2) There are no type casts in Go, only "type conversions". The spec (which is really easy to read) describes which type conversions work (and which don't).

Comment: Note: That's _not_ an [alias](https://go.dev/ref/spec#Alias_declarations). There also aren't any arrays in your question. Rather, what you have is just a simple type declaration, and slices.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, unfortunately Go does not allow direct conversion between different types, even if they are aliases. Alias is more like giving a new name to an existing type, but it does not provide any form of automatic conversion.

You need to manually iterate over the **[][]byte** and convert each **[]byte** to **Bytes** type.

Here's how you can do it:

```
package main

import "fmt"

type Bytes []byte

func main() {
    x := make([][]byte, 3)
    // Initializing byte slices for demonstration purposes
    for i := range x {
        x[i] = []byte{byte(i), byte(i+1)}
    }

    y := make([]Bytes, len(x))
    for i, v := range x {
        y[i] = Bytes(v)
    }

    fmt.Println("Hello, 世界", y)
}
```

This code manually iterates over **x**, converting each **[]byte** to **Bytes** and placing it in the corresponding position in **y**.

Comment: "Go does not allow direct conversion between different types [...]" [That's not true at all](https://go.dev/ref/spec#Conversions). "[...] even if they are aliases." Aliases are identifiers for a single type, not different types.

Answer (score 2):

> Is there a simple way to convert an array of arrays of byte to an array of Bytes

With an actual [alias](https://go.dev/ref/spec#Alias_declarations) you could do it. `Bytes` however is not an alias, it is a distinct type that only has the *underlying type* common with `[]byte`. The only option in this case is to use a loop.

See also [Can I convert `[]T1` to `[]T2` if `T1` and `T2` have the same underlying type?](https://go.dev/doc/faq#convert_slice_with_same_underlying_type).